# Compiler warnings are gibberish when building in russian-localized Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have strange symbols in output while building my solution:

```
1>WindowsForm.obj : warning LNK4248: эхЁрчЁх°хээр  ыхъёхьр TypeRef (01000030) фы  "SDL_Renderer"; юсЁрч эхы№ч  чряєёЄшЄ№
1>FatLinesArray.obj : warning LNK4248: эхЁрчЁх°хээр  ыхъёхьр TypeRef (01000014) фы  "SDL_Renderer"; юсЁрч эхы№ч  чряєёЄшЄ№
1>WindowsForm.obj : warning LNK4248: эхЁрчЁх°хээр  ыхъёхьр TypeRef (0100002F) фы  "SDL_Window"; юсЁрч эхы№ч  чряєёЄшЄ№
```

I have VS with russian language, how to fix this problem?

Comment: Just a guess - is it possible that you are using have a different Windows codepage than desired?

Comment: Codor, how to check it or change?
sashoalm, I'm using c++

Comment: Your best bet would be to just change the output language to English because otherwise you'll have a lot of non-fun time figuring out what the localized messages mean exactly and how to find help.

Comment: @sharptooth The output is gibberish, however, it's not Russian really.

Comment: @GALIAF95 I googled for "эхЁрчЁх°хээр  ыхъёхьр", and there are some hits - see http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-cli/thread640088.html and http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread12176 for example. Just google for the gibberish text.

Answer (score 3):

The error message has been emitted in Russian, probably in code page cp1251 as "нерешенным маркер TypeRef" (most likely - or something close). This has then been read by the console using an incorrect codepage (possibly cp866) and turned to rubbish. You can emulate this with Tcl:

```
% puts [encoding convertfrom cp866 [encoding convertto cp1251 "нерешенным маркер"]]
эхЁх°хээ√ь ьрЁъхЁ
```

The Visual Studio Options dialog has an "International Settings" page to select a language. You might try selecting something there. Otherwise, report the current selection and the output of `chcp` in a command prompt will give the current code page.

It would be interesting to know if building with `msbuild` in a console gives clear messages (ie: msbuild project.sln).